# Distribution of a Gaussian variable with a normally distributed mean

Tags: normal-distribution, finance, bivariate-distributions

Let $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y\sim(X,1)$, where $Y-X$ is independent of $X$. Then what is the PDF of $Y$? Specifically, I am interested in computing $P(Y<0\vert X>0)$.

For those interested in mathematical finance, this is equivalent to pricing a Slalom option (a derivative that pays out 1 if some index is above it's initial value at $T_{1}$ and below it's initial value at $T_{2}$ and 0 otherwise)  in a Normal model without drift.

Comment: 1. The PDF of $Y$ does not yield $p=P(Y<0\mid X>0)$. 2. The distribution of $Y$ is $N(0,2)$. 3. To compute $p$, note that $Y=X-Z$ with $Z$ standard normal independent of $X$ hence $p=P(X<Z\mid X>0)$ and that, by invariance of the distribution of $(X,Z)$ by rotations, $p=\frac14$.

Comment: @Did: From the assumption, it is not obvious why $Z$ is independent of $X$.

Comment: @Gordon Thank you for your comment, which I agree with. I should have mentioned that the underlying assumption is that $X=S_{1}$ and $Y=S_{2}$, where $S_{t}$ is a brownian motion, ie. the increments ($Y-X$) and $\Delta X=X-0$ are independent. I have made this clear in the question now.

Comment: @Gordon Actually this *is* obvious, being precisely what the assumption that $Y\sim N(X,1)$ means.

Comment: Thanks @Did and Myggen. Please see updates below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gordon's answer of $1/4$ is nice enough to make one wonder if there's an easier way to calculate it.

There is.   Specifically, let $Z = Y - X$.  Then $X$ and $Z$ are independent standard normals and you are looking for $P((X+Z) < 0 | X > 0)$.  By the definition of conditional probability, this is

$$ P(X+Z < 0, X > 0) \over P(X > 0) $$

and the denominator is $1/2$.  To evaluate the numerator, note that the joint distribution of $X$ and $Z$ is rotationally symmetric around the origin in the $XZ$-plane.  The region of the plane with $X + Z < 0$ and $X > 0$ simultaneously is a 45-degree sector, so the probability of falling in it is $1/8$; thus the conditional probability you're looking for is $(1/8)/(1/2) = 1/4$.

Comment: Argument posted as a comment Apr 10 at 18:48.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y\sim N(X, 1)$. Note that, for any $t\in\mathbb{R}$,
\begin{align*}
E\left(e^{it(Y-X)}\right) &=  E\left(E\left(e^{it(Y-X)} \mid X\right)\right)\\
&=E\left(e^{-it X} E\left(e^{it Y} \mid X\right)\right)\\
&=E\left(e^{-it X} e^{it X -\frac{t^2}{2}} \right)\\
&=e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}.
\end{align*}
That is, $Y-X\sim N(0, 1)$.
Moreover, for any $t_1, t_2 \in \mathbb{R}$,
\begin{align*}
E\left(e^{i\big((t_1X + t_2 (Y-X)\big)} \right) &= E\left(E\left(e^{i\big((t_1X + t_2 (Y-X)\big)}\mid X \right)\right)\\
&=E\left(e^{it_1X-it_2X}E\left(e^{it_2Y}\mid X \right)\right)\\
&=E\left(e^{it_1X-it_2X} e^{it_2X -\frac{t_2^2}{2}}\right)\\
&=e^{-\frac{t_1^2+t_2^2}{2}}\\
&=E\left(e^{it_1X}\right)E\left(e^{it_2(Y-X)}\right).
\end{align*}
That is, $X$ and $Y-X$ are independent. Then,
\begin{align*}
P(Y<0 \mid X >0) &= \frac{P(Y<0, X>0)}{P(X>0)}\\
&=2E\Big( P\big(Y<0, X>0 \mid X\big) \Big)\\
&=2E\Big(\pmb{1}_{\{X>0\}}\, P\big(Y-X<-X \mid X\big) \Big)\\
&=2E\big(\pmb{1}_{\{X>0\}}\, \Phi(-X)\big)\\
&=2E\big(\pmb{1}_{\{X>0\}} - \pmb{1}_{\{X>0\}}\,\Phi(X)\big)\\
&=2\bigg[\frac{1}{2} - \int_0^{\infty} \Phi(x) \Phi'(x) dx \bigg]\\
&= \frac{1}{4},
\end{align*}
where $\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution function of a standard normal random variable.

Comment: "Based on the background information of the financial problem" You could replace this rather mysterious invocation of some unspecified "background information" by the phrase "Based on the assumption that, conditionally on $X$, $Y\sim N(X,1)$". Or explain *precisely* which background information you are referring to.